# Create true / false - invisible / visible buttons via a map () array React.js Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, button, react-functional-component

[image]

Buttons were created using a map () Array, each button of questions when clicked shows an answer. The problem is that when you **click the question button it automatically hides and the answer button appears**, and when you **click the answer button it hides and the question button appears again**.

[image]

he following problem occurred, when I click on the answer button and it hides and I click on the same button as the question when checking the answer, it no longer accepts the sequence. In this case, I don't know how to do it?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-proskuriakova-1o0hf)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-buck-l83cp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Medi Thank you my friend I need to study more about ternary condition - id ? {... item, clicked:! item.clicked, disabled:! item.disabled}

Comment: @Medi The following problem occurred, when I click on the answer button and it hides and I click on the same button as the question when checking the answer, it no longer accepts the sequence. In this case, I don't know how to do it?

Comment: i'm not sure i fully understood the problem.

Comment: Check it now https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-buck-l83cp?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: André alright, i will check it

Comment: @Medi I believe this is related to the sequence of the array I will try to find out here too ... I put a second image at the beginning of the page to understand the problem

Comment: The problem is when the answer is removed, it was not removed from the sequence array too :https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-rubin-3xev6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Medi You are a genius would never be able to do this alone thanks again.

Comment: Andre anytime :D.